# BufferedReader found specific word in line, take the data from that line

Tags: java, arrays, file, bufferedreader

```
 br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((finalLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] reader = finalLine.split(",");

            String foundWord = "dod";

             for (String word : reader) {
              if (word.equals(foundWord)) {

              String NAME = reader[0];
              String PASSWORD = reader[1];
              String CONTACT_NO = reader[2];
              String EMAIL_ADDRESS = reader[3];
```

I'm currently using BufferedReader to read all lines from a text file, if found "dod" how to get the rest of the information in the same line 1. Please help.

the lines will have

```
(line 1) dod, 12345, 00112949, test@testacc.com 
(line 2) abc, 22222, 0004993, aaa@aaaac.com
```

in a textfile, If found dod, from above code, i want extract line 1 data and save in a variables.

Comment: If the word is found in a line what do you want to do with that line?

Comment: 'I don't know if found "dod"' what does that mean ? Do you want to find it ? Did your program find it ? I guess you want to ask how you can get the rest of the line once it found the word "dod". In this case, you already have the line: namely finalLine.

Comment: Hi sorry for the lack of information, the lines will have (line 1)dod, 12345, 00112949, test@testacc.com (line 2) abc, 22222, 0004993, aaa@aaaac.com in a textfile. If found dod, from above code, i want extract line1 data and save in a variable.

Comment: @javasimple please check if the code provided below works for you. You can store the information in any object easily.

Comment: If my answer works then why was it down-voted? That is surprising!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line;
        String name,pwd,contactNo,email;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/files/temp2.txt"));
            String foundWord = "dod";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] words = line.split(",");
                for (String word : words) {
                    if (word.equals(foundWord)) {
                        name = words[0];
                        pwd = words[1];
                        contactNo = words[2];
                        email = words[3];
                        System.out.println("Details: " +name + "-" + pwd + "-" + contactNo + "-" + email);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
             reader.close()
        }
    }
```

And the output will be:
`Details: dod-12345-00112949-test@testacc.com`. If you want you can store that information in an object.

Comment: Hi, I did not down-voted, somehow my question is, I guess someone else did.

Answer (score 0):

> if found "dod" how to get the rest of the information in the same line

You already have it, in the `finalLine` variable.

Answer (score -1):

check out this:

```
 public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        boolean found = false;
        Scanner line = new Scanner(new File("E:/temp.txt"));
        String foundWord = "dod";
        while (line.hasNextLine()) {

            String[] reader = line.nextLine().split(",");

            for (String word : reader) {
                if (word.equals(foundWord)) {

                    found = true;
                    String NAME = reader[0];
                    String PASSWORD = reader[1];
                    String CONTACT_NO = reader[2];
                    String EMAIL_ADDRESS = reader[3];
                    System.out.println(NAME + "\t" + PASSWORD + "\t"
                            + CONTACT_NO + "\t" + EMAIL_ADDRESS);
                }

            }

        }
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println(foundWord + " not found");
        }
    }

}
```

**Added** if not found condition

output:

```
dod  12345   00112949    test@testacc.com
```